# X Axis on Full Calendar Time settings for week and day

Tags: wordpress, fullcalendar

Could someone help me please I am not a developer/coder but am trying to use this calendar to display time intervals of 15 minutes rather than the current 30 minutes time intervals on the X axis of the display in the left hand column.

The events being booked are still 30 minutes long but start at 15 minute intervals, ie

8:00 pm - 8:30 pm
8:15 pm - 8:45 pm
8:30 pm - 9:00 pm
8:45 pm - 9:15 pm

I see the following code

//Determines the time-text that will be displayed on each event.
                    timeFormat:{ //Settings: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/timeFormat/
                        // for agendaWeek and agendaDay
                        agenda: 'h:mm{ - h:mm}', // 5:00 - 6:30

```
                    // for all other views
                    '': 'h(:mm)t'            // 7p
                },
```

but dont know what to do, can you help please bearing in mind i know very little about this or should I alter the java script?

Answer (score 1):

in fullcalendar.js change ....

```
setDefaults({
    allDaySlot: true,
    allDayText: 'all-day',
    firstHour: 6,
    slotMinutes: 15,   // <<< this
    defaultEventMinutes: 120,
    axisFormat: 'h(:mm)tt', 
    timeFormat: {
        agenda: 'h:mm{ - h:mm}'
    },
    dragOpacity: {
        agenda: .5
    },
    minTime: 0,
    maxTime: 24
});
```